# Validate time entered against current time

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, node-modules

I am trying to validate that the time is past the current time in my "if" statement. This is a javascript file.

```
addNewTodoSave() {
    var self = this;

    if (this.validateFields()) {
        var todos = State.getState().todos;
        if (!todos) {
            todos = [];
        }
        var date = moment(self.$el.find('.add-todo .date-input').val());
        var time;

        if (moment(self.$el.find('.add-todo .todo-time input').val(), 'hh:mm A').isValid()) {
            time = moment(self.$el.find('.add-todo .todo-time input').val(), 'hh:mm A').format('HH:mm:ss');
        } else if (moment(self.$el.find('.add-todo .todo-time input').val(), 'HH:mm').isValid()) {
            time = moment(self.$el.find('.add-todo .todo-time input').val(), 'HH:mm').format('HH:mm:ss');
        } else {
            time = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but I can not see where you are checking an entered time against "now" at all.

Comment: where would i put that and how?

Comment: Obviously you should put in your if condition where do you want to compare current time with your date object.

Comment: you can get the current date with new Date(), or for a number representation, Date.now().

Comment: @ArenHosepyan I want it to be the first condition to get checked